# How to deal with "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."

Tags: ssh, tty

```
ssh -t remotehost vim /tmp/x.txt
```

I know that I can run a command like the above.

But I would like to be able to run any local bash code in a remote machine. For this reason, I'd like to call the remote 'bash -s' so that can process any local bash code.

```
ssh -t remotehost 'bash -s' <<< vim /tmp/x.txt
```

However, the above example shows "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal." Is there any way to let ssh take local bash code via stdin and run it via the remote 'bash -s'? Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

```
ssh -t remotehost 'bash -s' <<< vim /tmp/x.txt
```

You're getting the "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated..." message because you're running ssh with a single `-t` option, when the standard input to the ssh process isn't a TTY. ssh prints that message specifically in this case. The [documentation for -t](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#t) says:

> **-t**
>   Force pseudo-terminal allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services. **Multiple -t options force tty allocation**, even if ssh has no local tty.

The `-t` command-line option is related to the ssh configuration option [**RequestTTY**](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#RequestTTY):

> **RequestTTY**
>   Specifies whether to request a pseudo-tty for the session. The argument may be one of: no (never request a TTY), yes (always request a TTY when standard input is a TTY), force (always request a TTY) or auto (request a TTY when opening a login session). This option mirrors the -t and -T flags for ssh(1).

A single `-t` is equivalent to "RequestTTY yes", while two of them is equivalent to "RequestTTY force".

If you want your remote command(s) to run with a TTY, then specify `-t` twice:

```
ssh -tt remotehost 'bash -s' <<< vim /tmp/x.txt
or
ssh -t -t remotehost 'bash -s' <<< vim /tmp/x.txt
```

ssh will allocate a TTY for the remote system and it won't print that message.

If the command(s) being run on the remote system don't require a TTY, you can leave the `-t` option out:

```
ssh remotehost 'bash -s' <<< vim /tmp/x.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following might suit your purposes:

```bash
vim /tmp/x.txt ; ssh remotehost 'bash -s' < /tmp/x.txt
```

The first expression (`vim ...`) allows you to specify the commands you want to execute remotely as a local file called `/tmp/x.txt`; the second expression (`ssh ...`) calls the remote bash interpreter, and sends the contents of your local file to it for execution. Note that you do not need the `-t` option for `ssh` in this case (which gave rise to the pseudo-terminal warning), and that you do not need to use a [here string](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) (`<<<`) but can use the normal file input operator (`<`).

This solution seems to work for, e.g., the following file contents:

```
echo These commands are being executed on $HOSTNAME
echo This is a second command
```

Comment: I forgot to mention you can remove the `-t` option from the `ssh` command in this case, which should get rid of the pseudo-terminal warning. I edited the answer above; the current command now seems to work correctly on my system (it executes the local file remotely without showing the warning).

Comment: If this answer does not solve your question, consider clarifying the actual commands you want to execute remotely.