# Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal. ssh using batch script to execute script on remote host

Tags: bash, batch-file, ssh, zenity

I have a batch file

```
#content of batch file
@echo off
plink.exe -ssh user@IP.address -m C:\Users\My\Documents\command_test.txt -i C:\Users\My\Desktop\PUTTYKEY.ppk
```

which connects to a remote ubuntu host using plink.exe and runs the following command to set off the script

```
#content of command_test.txt
/home/user/script.sh
```

The script requires user input to select files from a second remote host using zenity file selection and an OpenSSH connection

```
#code snippet from script.sh
ssh -X Remote_vm_user@Remote2.IP.address <<EOF
zenity --title "please select location of data" --file-selection --directory > directory_selected.tmp
echo "========================="
echo "user selected"
cat directory_selected.tmp
echo "========================="
exit
EOF
```

This works when executing the script directly when connected using PuTTy

However, when executed using the batch file it returns the error;

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

I have tried using a variety of options to force it as suggested [How to deal with "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648572/how-to-deal-with-pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-t)

`-t` and `-tt` and `-T` and `-t -t`
These don't work, no errors are displayed, it just eventually times out

very new to stack overflow so apologies if poor question, suggest edits and I'll amend immediately

Comment: Just randomly trying something does not mean it will work. the `-tt` option is available on specific *nix shells. What does your help provide? i.e `ssh --help` or `ssh -?`

Comment: @Gerhard 

`ssh --help
usage: ssh [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
           [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]`

Comment: Where is your EOF marker in the commands to be executed remotely?

Comment: @RamanSailopal I dont understand, please could you elaborate?

Comment: So you are using `OpenSSH`?

Comment: @Gerhard
Will add more details to the question, 1 min

Comment: @Gerhard yes, using OpenSSH, had to go check that haha

Comment: Run `plink --help`? Do you see the `-t -T     enable / disable pty allocation` paramter?

Comment: yes I see the that =)

Comment: So try `plink.exe -t -ssh user@IP.address -m C:\Users\My\Documents\command_test.txt -i C:\Users\My\Desktop\PUTTYKEY.ppk` where `-T` will disable pseudo pty. I am guessing here because I do not have plink running.

Comment: Unfortunately everything executes the same as before, same error, with the exception of some weird characters `[3J[H[2J` appearing

Comment: You have specified EOF as part of a heredoc but then don't seem to have used EOF at the end of the list of commands?

Comment: ok, I see now that you are issuing ssh using plink and then executing another script to do the ssh.. but Raman has a point, you do not have EOF as the last command in the list.

Comment: my apologies, I have actually got EOF in there, it just didnt copy paste over - EDIT have added `EOF` to end of commands

Comment: edit- have added in headers to code snippets to make their origins more clear